# Can't find pointer error with my Binary Search Tree implementation?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to C++ and I can't find why the root of the tree changes whenever I add anything to the tree. It must be a pointer problem but I can't figure it out. For example:

```
BST bst;
bst.insert(5);
bst.insert(2);
```

I get the correct output when I insert 5, but when I insert 2 it says:

`Inserted 2 to the left of 2.`

Node class:

```
class Node
{
// Let BST directly access members.
friend class BST;
public:
    // Constructor
    Node(int i);
    int getValue();
protected:
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

// Constructor
Node::Node(int i)
{
    value = i;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
}

int Node::getValue()
{
 return value;
}
```

BST class:

```
class BST
{
    public:
        BST();
        void insert(int i);
        void print();
        void print(Node *n);
    private:
        // root of the tree
        Node *root;
};

BST::BST()
{
    root = 0;
}

void BST::insert(int i)
{
    Node *cur = this->root;
    Node *prev;
    Node new_node(i);
    if(cur == 0)
    {
        this->root = &new_node;
        cout << "Root is empty, insert " << this->root->value << " as root." << endl;
        return;
    }
    while(cur != 0)
    {
        prev = cur;
        if(i <= cur->value)
        {
            cur = cur->left;
            if(cur == 0)
            {
                prev->left = &new_node;
                cout << "Inserted " << prev->left->value << " to the left of " << prev->value << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(i > cur->value)
        {
            cur = cur->right;
            if(cur == 0)
            {
                prev->right = &new_node;
                cout << "Inserted " << prev->right->value << " to the right     of " << prev->value << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void BST::print()
{
    print(this->root);
}

void BST::print(Node *n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    print(n->left);
    cout << n->value << " " << endl;
    print(n->right);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you stepped through line by line during execution using a debugger?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Have you noticed that you are not allocating your nodes? You create them by value inside `insert` method and they are deleted as soon as your code exit it. It might be unrelated to your issue but it will bite you anyway later on.

Comment: @maddening: I reckon that's _precisely_ the problem. The symptoms fit.

Comment: @maddening Ah right so I didn't even create my nodes correctly... I thought `Node new_node(i)` was enough in C++ to create the object. Thanks.

Comment: @BelegNeurion: It is. It's just not enough to create an object that lasts as long as you need it to last.

Answer (score 4):

`Node new_node(i);` this creates a local variable. Later you assign its address to `root`. Note that using the data written at the address of a local variable outside of its scope will invoke **undefined behavior**. You need to allocate dynamic memory and later take care to deallocate it.

Comment: Yes, this. The addresses in the tree are likely all the same, hence the "replacing value" behaviour the OP has seen when [undefinedly] dereferencing them.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the address of a local object:

```
Node new_node(i);
```

...

```
this->root = &new_node;
```

When the local object goes out of scope, further use of that address is undefined behavior.

You wanted:

```
   Node* new_node = new Node(i);
```

...

```
   this->root = new_node;
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was trying to just create a node and then point root to that without having to create another pointer. Is there a way I can do it this way? Thanks.

Comment: @BelegNeurion: No, you _need_ to "create another pointer". How can you have multiple, different pointers in your tree without "creating another pointer"? It's like asking how to have ten cars but only actually purchase one. At the moment you're renting one car ten times, and giving it back to the rental agency before you've even driven it once let alone ten times. :)

Comment: Please stop recommending `new T` to people. It’s 2015.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If there is supposed to be some insight hidden in that comment, you'll need some link or explanation.

Comment: @JSF I would have hoped that it was self-explanatory: don’t use `new` in your code, it’s bad. Use an appropriate smart pointer with a builder function (e.g. `make_unique`) or some other memory management construct. There’s rarely a good reason for using `new` at all any more, and certainly not here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok I understand now thanks. I guess my confusion is with instantiating objects. What is the correct way of doing it? And what does `Node new_node(i);` actually do as doesn't it call the constructor?

Comment: @BelegNeurion: It creates an object, with automatic storage duration (which includes, among other things, invoking the constructor). It's a perfectly reasonable and often desired way to create an object. However, it is not how _you_ need to create an object _in this particular circumstance_. Which book are you using? These are the basics.